# Wordpress Custom Query: Combining Two Functions

Tags: php, mysql, query

I'm a bit new to php and am having some trouble combining the functionality of two custom queries in Wordpress in order to (1) get pagination to work properly, and (2) sort my posts according to a voting plugin.

**(1) The following is a custom query, which is working with pagination, but does not sort my posts according to votes (set in a voting plugin).**

```
$total = "
SELECT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID         =   wpostmeta.post_id
AND wposts.post_status  =   'publish'
AND wposts.post_type IN     ('youtube', 'vimeo')
GROUP BY wposts.ID
";

$totalposts = $wpdb->get_results($total, OBJECT);
$ppp = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
$wp_query->found_posts = count($totalposts);
$wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $ppp); 
$on_page = intval(get_query_var('paged'));  

if($on_page == 0){ $on_page = 1; }  
$offset = ($on_page-1) * $ppp;

$wp_query->request = "
SELECT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID         =   wpostmeta.post_id
AND wposts.post_status  =   'publish'
AND wposts.post_type IN     ('youtube', 'vimeo')
GROUP BY wposts.ID
LIMIT $ppp OFFSET $offset
";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request, OBJECT);
```

**(2) The following is another custom query. When this query is combined with the function in #3, it does sort my posts according to votes. However it does not work with pagination.**

```
$enddate = date('Y-m-d');
$increment_date = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime( $enddate ));
$enddate = date("Y-m-d", $increment_date);

$increment_date = strtotime("-1 month", strtotime( $enddate ));
$startdate = date("Y-m-d", $increment_date);

$query = "
SELECT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID         = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wposts.post_status  = 'publish'
AND wposts.post_type IN ('youtube', 'vimeo')
AND post_date           >= '$startdate'
AND post_date           <= '$enddate'
GROUP BY wposts.ID
";
```

**(3) And the function for sort according to votes is...**

```
function ShowPostByVotes($query) {

global $wpdb, $voteiu_databasetable;
$upperlimit = get_option('voteiu_limit');
if ($upperlimit == '') { $upperlimit = 100; } $lowerlimit = 0;

$votesarray = array();

    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

$query_limited = $query." LIMIT ".$lowerlimit.", ".$upperlimit;

$posttablecontents = mysql_query( $query_limited );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($posttablecontents)) {
    $post_id = $row['ID'];
    $vote_array = GetVotes($post_id, "array");
    array_push($votesarray, array(GetVotes($post_id)));
}
array_multisort($votesarray, SORT_DESC, $pageposts);
$output = $pageposts;
return $output;
}
```

My difficulty is that I can't seem to create a query/function that both sorts my posts by votes, and also works with pagination...I apologize I know it's a bit of a big question, but I've been struggling with this for a few days with no luck and can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I'll move it over tomorrow if no answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using the WP_Query object and have it order your posts by a meta field:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Doing so will handle sorting and pagination out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Denis. This was the initial plan, but where we are querying the posts so much it really quickens things up to have the votes stored in their own table, and join that to our posts. It's a bit slow to query by the custom meta. But thanks again.

Comment: There are join filters that you can use for this. See the source code of the WP_Query object.

Comment: Thanks Denis I'll have a look and see if I can figure it out...it would be great to be able to stick with WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `orderby` your `ShowPostByVotes` query in the (1) custom query? Are they accessible to each other?